# a=b, and when a change, will b still equal a?

Tags: python

Sorry for a very simply question in python numpy
When I trying to let a equal to b (as following code)

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array((1,2))
b=np.array((3,4))
b=a
a=np.array((5,6))
```

what i get is:

```
a=array([5,6])
b=array([1,2])
```

where i suppose it is nothing weird.
However, when I try to edit one of the value in the array of a (as followed):

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array((1,2))
b=np.array((3,4))
b=a
a[0]=100
```

I get:

```
a=array([100,2])
b=array([100,2])
```

So i was just wondering why b is changing as well?
and how should I do if i wanna get a result:

```
a=array([100,2])
b=array([1,2])
```

Sorry for my fundamental knowledge of python is not good, but this problem is really confusing me and I do hope someone willing to help me to explain this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`b = numpy.copy(a)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html)

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple really. Let me explain line by line:

```
a=np.array((1,2))
```

This sets up a `pointer` to the object `np.array((1,2))` that can be accessed by calling `a`. The same thing happens with `b=np.array((3,4))`

Calling `b=a` changes b's pointer. It now points to the same object as `a`. So now `b` equals `np.array((1,2))`. Next you call:

```
a=np.array((5,6))
```

This changes `a`'s pointer to point to the object `np.array((5,6))`. So `a` and `b` are no longer pointing to the same thing.

`a[0]=100` changes the values in both `a` and `b` because here you are changing the object they are both pointing not, not changing the pointer itself.

If you wish to avoid this you can create a `copy` of `a`. E.g:

```
b = np.copy(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do an `=` you are not creating a new array, but instead you are just setting the reference `b` to point at the same array that `a` is pointing at.

Below will actually create a new array by copying:

```
b=numpy.copy(a)
```

Similarly if you want to do it for a list

```
b = a[:]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply
I tried the advice and it gave me the same result when i trying to change a[0] value in later
b changing together as well